# Why is my Checkbutton checked by default?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function that receives a list and creates a `Checkbutton` for each element in this list. This is sort of menu. But when I call this function, every `Checkbutton` are already checked, how to fix it?

```
def ask_event(args):
    root = tk.Tk()
    eventToReturn = tk.StringVar(root)
    for i,arg in enumerate(args):
        tk.Checkbutton(root, text = arg, onvalue = arg, variable = eventToReturn).grid(row = i, column = 1)
    tk.Button(root, text = "Confirm", command = root.quit).grid()

    root.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
    value = eventToReturn.get()

    return value
```

Comment: Please add [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tkinter checkbutton has 3 states:

1. checked
2. unchecked
3. a "semi-checked" state, referred to as "tri-state mode". This state is useful when you have multiple checkbuttons arranged in a hierarchy - while some of the "child" checkbuttons are checked, the "parent" checkbutton should be in this 3rd state.

Per default, the 3 states correspond to these 3 values:

- checked = 1
- unchecked = 0
- greyed out = anything else

(These values can be changed with the `onvalue` and `offvalue` parameters, see [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#patterns).)

---

This explains why your checkbutton appears checked by default: A new `StringVar`'s value is the empty string, which corresponds to the special 3rd state.

To set the checkbutton's state to "unchecked", you have to set the variable to the `offvalue` (0 per default):

```
eventToReturn = tk.StringVar(root)
eventToReturn.set('0')
```

Alternatively, you can use a `BooleanVar` or `IntVar`, which are set to 0 by default:

```
eventToReturn = tk.IntVar()
```

Comment: _"a StringVar is not capable of saving the checkbutton's state correctly "_ - that is a false statement. It's perfectly acceptable to use a `StringVar` with a checkbutton.  While the state is either on or off (or the third _tristate_ value), the values themselves can be any arbitrary strings.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're correct, but I can't find any information about this 3rd state. The checkbutton appears greyed out and checked, but what does this state actually mean? Would you care to write an answer?

Comment: The third state is mostly useful when you have a hierarchy of checkbuttons. If you have a group of checkbuttons where some are checked and some are not, their parent checkbutton will have this third value. The canonical tcl/tk documentation describes it here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm#M6

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the info, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: The tri-state checkbutton isn't necessarily grayed out. It depends on the platform that you're running on. Also, to set the checkbuttons state to "unchecked" you have to set it to the _offvalue_, which may or may not be zero. Here's a decent screenshot of the third state on different platforms: http://www.tkdocs.com/images/w_checkbutton_all.png

Comment: @BryanOakley I did mention that 1 and 0 were the default values and could be changed, but I made it more clear now. I also changed the description of the 3rd state, but do you happen to know if it has an "official" name?

Comment: The official documentation calls it the "tri-state mode".